# Why isn't my localscript working?

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I am basically trying to script a GUI control panel that allows users to accelerate the train with a power lever (in the GUI) and a reverser (Forward, Neutral, Reverse)

I have made two scripts. One is a localscript, the other being a regular script. The regular script enables the GUI on a player's screen when the player sits in the seat. The localscript is what makes the GUI function.

I've scripted the entire thing but only the regular script seems to function, The localscript does not seem to function as it is scripted to. The GUI appears on the screen but when pressed it does nothing.

Here are the contents of the localscript
http://pastebin.com/raw/XnT2Bi2X

Here's are all the objects in the Workspace that is mentioned and relevant to the script:
https://s31.postimg.org/4hd2up2ij/Screen_Shot_2016_06_24_at_11_15_21_AM.png

What are the errors in the localscript that is not allowing the GUI to function as its scripted to?

(I apologize for the long script and thank you for your help in advanced)

Note: The codes are Lua (which are used on the ROBLOX Studio Platform)

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for writing out a  clear and concise question. Most of the questions under this tag are all over the place :).

I would verify that you `LocalScript` instance is being properly initialized inside of the `Player` instance that is sitting down. Looking over your `LocalScript`'s code, I don't see any errors that would cause the GUI not to function (if the `LocalScript` is being initialized properly), which leads me to believe the `LocalScript` isn't even running. If you are loading the `LocalScript` into the player on spawn (so, putting it into the `PlayerScripts` folder), there's your problem. This would cause the GUI to not be set up properly, as it hasn't been inserted into the players `PlayerGui` instance yet, so the `LocalScript` won't be able to hook up the `MouseButton1Click` events or anything of that sort.

So, make sure that the `LocalScript` starts running once the player sits in the seat (use the regular `Script` that displays the GUI to also move a copy of the `LocalScript` into the player). This will (hopefully) initialize the `LocalScript` properly, and allow it to hook into the GUI.

If this doesn't work, check your `output` window for any blatant errors, and post em here.

Cheers!

-widoreu

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, when I copied the localscript and placed into the script, it did not work. Here were the errors I received in the output window https://s31.postimg.org/3khthxy0r/Screen_Shot_2016_07_02_at_10_43_38_PM.png

Comment: Hmm, can I see where the localScript is placed at the moment?

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/4p9623g23/Screen_Shot_2016_07_02_at_10_58_47_PM.png

Comment: Does the LocalScript properly execute when the user sits on the seat? Try adding a `print` statement in the LocalScript code to see if it's executing at the right time.

Comment: I put a print statement at the end of the localscript and it does not appear in the output at all. It seems that the localscript is completely unresponsive.

Comment: Any clues what the issue might be?